# How to make a connection checker between a socket server and client?

Tags: c#, python, sockets

I have a socket connection between a python server and a `c#` client, so I'm trying to define a boolean variable `_status` in the client side on which I store the status of the connection (true or false). I have tried the code below but it does not work; it always returns a false status, what wrong with it? Is there any other good idea to do it better than this?

c# code:

```
        public string ReceiveStatus()
        {         
            sc.SetAddress("127.0.0.1");
            sc.SetPort("20015");
            sc.ServerConnect();
            return sc.ReceiveQuery();
        }
        new Thread(() => 
        {
            var task = Task.Run(() => ReceiveStatus());
            Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true; 
            while(true)
            {
                sc.SendQuery("Are you here?");
                if (task.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)))
                {
                    if (task.Result == "Yes")
                    {
                        _status = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _status = false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    _status = false; 
                }
            }
        }).Start();
```

python code:

```
    while True:
        try:
            msg = ReceiveQuery(client)
            if msg == "Are you here?":
                SendQuery("Yes",client)
        except Exception as e:
            print ('an exception has been generated')
```

Comment: The idea is good; ping protocol (echo request/echo reply) is the way to check connection. What is the value of `task.Result` when it's returned from Python after `task.Wait`?

Comment: `task.Result`has the value `not yet computed`

Comment: Can you provide also the code for `ReceiveStatus()`?

Comment: @RolandBär: done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I don't know the implementation of your socket connection object `sc` I see some problems in your code:

- `ReceiveStatus()` contains both connecting the socket and receiving data through the socket. You should split this up into connecting and receiving.
- As `ReceiveStatus()` is started in a Task it could be possible that `sc.SendQuery("Are you here?");` is called before the socket is connected.
- While `SendQuery()` is called in the infinite loop, `ReceiveQuery()` is called only once in the Task. As soon as the task has ended you will never read new information again.

Comment: this is helpful!